# Matlab: Repeat iteration until condition is met

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I am trying to learn Matlab as someone with an R background. I have the following program written for an iteration that I would like to repeat until the specified condition is met. I believe that I have all of code written for Matlab, except for the command that the iteration should repeat infinitely times until the condition is met (denoted below).

Would someone be able to tell me how to translate this to Matlab syntax? I think that I should be using a while-loop, but I'm not sure since the iterations should continue until a condition is met rather than continuing while some condition is met. Is there an until equivalent? Thank you!

```
function xn = newton_v2(f,fd,x0,tol)

% newton iteration

xn = x0;
repeat{ %%% 'This is how I would begin the repeat command in R'

    % evaluate function and derivative
    fxn = feval(f,xn);
    fdxn = feval(fd,xn);

    % newton iteration step
    xnp1 = xn - fxn/fdxn;

        if(abs(xnp1 - xn)/abs(xnp1) < tol)
            xn<-xnp1
        end

    % update
    xn = xnp1;
} %%% 'This is how I would end the repeat command in R'
end
```

Also, please let me know if you see anything else wrong in my Matlab code.

Comment: maybe `while loop`? http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html

Comment: Doing something until a condition is met is the same as doing something while that condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great with R syntax, but you would have two options 1.pass in an array of values to a matlab for loop and iterate through them. Then graph it to find the best solution and try to get more precise from there 2. Set a condition on a while loop. I think you are looking more for a while loop, so you'll put your condition in there. It may be more computationally heavy, but depending on the funct. may be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the syntax for the `for` loop?

If you are trying to create Newton's method, see my own implementation script

- y is the function
- x0 - first initial value
- n - # of xns to approximate

  ```
  function Xn = newtonsMethod (y,x0,n,startDomain,endDomain)

  %the tangent line at any point on the curve
  y1 = matlabFunction(diff(sym(y)));
  Xn = x0;
  x= linspace(startDomain,endDomain,1000);

  %recursive call for the newton formula
   for i = 1 : n

      %find the tangent line
      L =@(x)(y1(Xn).*(x-Xn)+y(Xn));

      %find the root
      Xn = Xn - (y(Xn)./y1(Xn));

  end
  end
  ```

This might be not the best way to do it. but it could help!

Answer (score 0):

I do the Newton method with a while loop though the recursive version in the answer by hamaney is interesting.  I do this by passing a function handle, initial guess and tolerance to a function.

```
function x1 = NewtonMethod(f,x,tol)
% dtol is calculated from eps based on the function handle...not shown
xi = f(x); % initial guess
dxi = (f(x+dtol) - f(x-dtol)) / (2 * dtol);
x1 = x - xi / dxi;
while (abs(x1 - x) < tol)
    x = x1;
    xi = f(x);
    dxi = (f(x+dtol) - f(x-dtol)) / (2 * dtol);
    x1 = x - xi / dxi;
end
end
```

There is a problem with this approach.  If the initial guess is poorly conditioned or the function unbounded it is possible for this to be an infinite loop.  Because of this I include a loop counter and normally break when that counter reaches a `maxSteps` value.

Adding the inifinite loop protection looks something like this.

```
xi = f(x); % initial guess
dxi = (f(x+dtol) - f(x-dtol)) / (2 * dtol);
x1 = x - xi / dxi;
loopCounter = 0;
while (abs(x1 - x) < tol)
    x = x1;
    xi = f(x);
    dxi = (f(x+dtol) - f(x-dtol)) / (2 * dtol);
    x1 = x - xi / dxi;
    loopCounter = loopCounter + 1;
    if loopCounter > maxSteps
        % include warning message
        break
    end
end
```